# How to deal with unapproved licenses files in Cassandra repository while issuing ant?

Tags: build, cassandra, ant

I git clone from github, make sure that I have been equipped with java8, python2.7, ant1.10.12, and ran into an exception when issue command `ant` in the directory of cassandra.

The rat.txt then told me there are more than 200 files deemed as Unapproved licences. For nearly all the night I tried googling any key words I can come up with but it seems that no one had ever met this situation.

Now I am really curious that what can I do under this circumstance, rather than refactoring those 200+ files manually which is definitely not a appropriate workaround.

I would really appreciate for any help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution seems to be a simple `-Drat.skip=true`. Anyone new to build Cassandra from source may not know this parameter, I hope this thread may help you if the offcial document not.